# Tar and save results directly to an SSH directory

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, tar

I have a server that I would like to make a tar backup of, but the server itself doesn't have enough disk space that is equal to the data it contains. Therefore, I would like to tar it *directly* to an ssh directory, such that it would dump the tar data into the ssh target without taking huge temporary disk space from the source server.

The server is supposed to do an ssh connection and use a directory of the form:

```
ssh user@server.com:/home/user/backupfolder/
```

Is this possible with simple Linux terminal piping or even a simpler way?

Comment: You can try SSHFS which is FUSE based filesystem. Here is a good guide how to install it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible! Do the following from the server you're backing up:

```
tar czv <stuff to backup> | ssh user@server.com 'cat > /home/user/backupfolder/backup.tar.gz'
```

This instructs `tar` to output the archive to stdout, which is piped and sent over `ssh` to be saved to a remote file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and let you know :-)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I have a followup question on that if you don't mind. I usually pipe tar to openssl to encrypt my packages with `tar zcpf / | openssl des3 -salt | dd of=backup.des3`. Could you please tell me how to achieve the same while directly dumping through ssh, like the answer you provided? In other words, I would like to have the archive encrypted too. I tried achieving this by adding the openssl part to your solution, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tar zcp / | openssl des3 -salt | ssh ...` should work. If it doesn't, something else might be wrong (you may want to post that as a separate question).