# Tar and encrypt with OpenSSL and dump the result directly to an ssh server

Tags: encryption, ssh, openssl, backup, tar

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058584/tar-and-save-results-directly-to-an-ssh-directory) where I asked about dumping a tar'ed folder to an SSH target. This is useful when backing up servers that have no enough disk space. The solution I got and it works, is this:

```
tar czv <stuff to backup> | ssh user@server.com 'cat > /home/user/backupfolder/backup.tar.gz'
```

But the problem now is that I usually pipe tar to openssl to encrypt my packages with

```
tar zcpf / | openssl des3 -salt | dd of=backup.des3
```

**My question:** Now I wanna do the same, but with dumping the resulting archive directly into the SSH target, as given in [that answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058584/tar-and-save-results-directly-to-an-ssh-directory) but with OpenSSL encryption.

I tried the following:

```
tar zcpf / | openssl des3 -salt | ssh user@backupserver.com 'cat > /some/dir/backup.tar.gz'
```

This causes a race between the password asked by OpenSSL and the password asked by ssh, which results in a problem making OpenSSL refuse the input password when repeating it.

**Note:** Using a public key for logging in without a password isn't considered a useful solution for my case. (EDIT: Also passing the password to OpenSSL is not a solution).

Is there a way to do this without problems? I see the solution as to have OpenSSL ask me about the password, and then ssh ask me about the password, with no racing between them.

Thanks in advance. If you require any additional details, please ask.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww would you like me to show you 500 other questions like mine on stackoverflow?

Comment: No thanks. But you might getter help quicker if you ask on the correct site. Help with using commands is usually rendered at Super User.

Comment: @jww Thanks. My question had already been answered before you posted your comment.

Comment: @jww I can accept it only tomorrow, because I wrote it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to create my own bash script that will do the job and fix the problem. Remember that the script has to be run as root if you want to backup the root folder. You can make it fancier by adding root checker at the beginning of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirToBackup=/
targetDir=/path/to/encrypted/backup/file.des3
sshuser=user
sshserver=myserver.com

read -s -p "Enter Encryption Password: " mypassword1
printf "\n"
read -s -p "Repeat Encryption Password: " mypassword2
printf "\n"

#make sure the passwords match
if [ "$mypassword1" != "$mypassword2" ]
then
        echo "Passwords don't match! Exiting."
        exit
else
#if they match, make sure they're not empty
        if [ -z "$mypassword1" ]
        then
                echo "Password cannot be empty... Exiting."
        else
                tar zcp $dirToBackup | openssl des3 -salt -pass pass:$mypassword1 | ssh ${sshuser}@${sshserver} "dd of=${targetDir}"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: How about recursive folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can  pass the password with `pass` argument to encryption.

This should prevent seeking of encryption password later in time and then clash with the password prompt for SSH.

`tar zcpf / | openssl des3 -salt -pass pass:1234 | ssh user@backupserver.com 'cat > /some/dir/backup.tar.gz'`

EDIT:

This answer does not suit the OP's requirement. The edit made later mentions that passing password as argument is not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, that's even worse than using the public key for ssh.

Comment: Ok. I got you. Just curious. How do you intend to pass the password for the user who wants to use the encrypted password?

Comment: The user is me. I would like to create a script for occasional full backup of my server, but I don't want to expose the password or make my backup server permanently accessible.

Comment: Then how about seeking password from the script? You then take this then execute tar operations? Embed password provided into the openssl command?

Comment: If there is a way to prompt for the password, input it in hidden form without exposing its characters and confirm it as openssl does, and then pass it to openssl as command line parameter, that would be a great solution!

Comment: I solved the problem myself. Thanks for the hints. Check my new answer.